# post file by jquery and save it using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, post

I have used $.post thousands of times. but this time along with posting data I want to post a GIF image file too. and using asp.net C# I need to save the file on server but I have no idea how to send the file using jquery and how to fetch it using c#. I want to do something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="img"  />


$.post('request.aspx',{name: 'someValue', price: somePrice, img: $('#img').val()}, function(){
alert('data saved');
});
```

and using c# in request.aspx fetch posted data and use them:

```
 string name = Request.Form["name"];
 string price = Request.Form["price"];
 //and some how get the image...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar but used the Canvas element to achieve it:

```
 dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
                    jQuery.post("/admin/Handlers/HelpImageUpload.ashx", { img: dataURL }, function (data) {

                        pcHelp.Show();
                    });
```

On the handler:

var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(context.Request["img"]);

Comment: As other answer points out though, if it's an image and a file input type, then really you should be able to pick it out using the build in controls

Comment: this seems doable but as gif images might be big (max 1MB) wouldn't it be a problem? and will it work in old browsers like ie6 , ie7?

Comment: I used: var reader = new FileReader(); reader.readAsDataURL(file); instead of canvas that doesn't work in older versions of IE

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload the file using POST request what I suggest is to embed your upload control in a Form and do a simple form submit. If you want to handle the callback for your Form post, use [jQuery From plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)